# Unable to find a specification for `AFNetworking (~> 2.1.0)`

Tags: ruby, rubymotion

am on a rubymotion project

have required afmotion in rake file, gem file and bundle installed. I get the above error when I try to run rake pod:install.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Make sure you have the cocoapods gem installed, then run 
`pod setup`
If for some reason that doesn't solve the problem, remove the cocoapods directory entirely with
`rm -rf ~/.cocoapods` and try to `pod setup` again.

Comment: I was just being impatient on my connection with pod setup, took like 15 minutes to gather from master on my crappy connection

Comment: Another pod was failing for me, and this answer solved my problem. Thanks.

Comment: It worked for me. But pod setup was not mentioned in official site. https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html